# How to not edit in a project in cloudshell?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I don't want to edit in a specific project in cloudshell, but it automatically directs me to one. How can I exit out of it and just not edit in a specific project?

Answer (score 2):

You can just unset the project with the Cloud SDK command:

```
gcloud config unset project
```

then you can validate if there is no project associated with it:

```
gcloud config get-value project
```